# Outlook-vba type mismatch error encountered when trying to run macro

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm encountering the "Type mismatch" popup error when trying to run the code below.

My code is used to save incoming emails from various recipients as .txt files in a given location.

The computer has been restarted and before the restart I could execute without problems.

What can be the issue?

```
Sub SaveEmail(msg As Outlook.MailItem)
  ' save as text
  If InStr(msg.Subject, "OBW cell status") > 0 Then
    msg.SaveAs "C:\Users\emirmot\Desktop\Tag Tool\obw\email" & Format(msg.CreationTime, "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & ".txt", olTXT
  End If

  If InStr(msg.Subject, "Yoigo Cells Down Report") > 0 Then
    msg.SaveAs "C:\Users\emirmot\Desktop\Tag Tool\yoigo\email" & Format(msg.CreationTime, "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & ".txt", olTXT
  End If

  If InStr(msg.Subject, "KPN 3G") > 0 Then
    msg.SaveAs "C:\Users\emirmot\Desktop\Tag Tool\kpn\3gemail" & Format(msg.CreationTime, "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & ".txt", olTXT
  End If

  If InStr(msg.Subject, "KPN 2G") > 0 Then
    msg.SaveAs "C:\Users\emirmot\Desktop\Tag Tool\kpn\2gemail" & Format(msg.CreationTime, "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & ".txt", olTXT
  End If

  If InStr(msg.Subject, "KPN 4G") > 0 Then
    msg.SaveAs "C:\Users\emirmot\Desktop\Tag Tool\kpn\4gemail" & Format(msg.CreationTime, "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & ".txt", olTXT
  End If

  If InStr(msg.Sender, "GAUSS.ADMIN@dcn.h3g.it") > 0 Then
    msg.SaveAs "C:\Users\emirmot\Desktop\Tag Tool\h3g\gauss\" & Replace(msg.Subject, ":", "") & ".txt", olTXT
  End If

  Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
  Dim saveFolder As String
  saveFolder = "C:\Users\emirmot\Desktop\Tag Tool\h3g\"

  Dim saveFoldersiu As String
  saveFoldersiu = "C:\Users\emirmot\Desktop\Tag Tool\yoigo\siu\"

  Dim saveFoldernodata As String
  saveFoldernodata = "C:\Users\emirmot\Desktop\Tag Tool\yoigo\"

  Dim saveFoldermobistar As String
  saveFoldermobistar = "C:\Users\emirmot\Desktop\Tag Tool\mobistar\"

  Dim saveFolderip_sa_tools As String
  saveFolderip_sa_tools = "C:\Users\emirmot\Desktop\Tag Tool\yoigo\ip_sa_tools\"

  Dim saveFolder_yoigoreport As String
  saveFolder_yoigoreport = "C:\wamp\www\cell_avail_report\uploads\"

  Dim saveFolder_h3gtn As String
  saveFolder_h3gtn = "C:\Users\emirmot\Desktop\Tag Tool\h3g\tn_temp\"

  If InStr(msg.Subject, "H3G IT") > 0 Then
     For Each objAtt In msg.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & Format(msg.ReceivedTime, "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
  End If

  If InStr(msg.Subject, "All RNC Hourly Iublink State") > 0 Then
     For Each objAtt In msg.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFoldernodata & "\" & Format(msg.ReceivedTime, "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
  End If

  If InStr(msg.Subject, "SIU") > 0 Then
     For Each objAtt In msg.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFoldersiu & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
  End If

  If InStr(msg.Subject, "CELLS STATUS") > 0 Then
     For Each objAtt In msg.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFoldermobistar & "\" & Format(msg.ReceivedTime, "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
  End If

  If InStr(msg.Subject, "OneFM Alarms - Generic message") > 0 Then
     For Each objAtt In msg.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolderip_sa_tools & "\" & Format(msg.ReceivedTime, "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS") & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
  End If

  If InStr(msg.Sender, "bis4g@report.com") > 0 Then
     For Each objAtt In msg.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder_yoigoreport & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
  End If

  If InStr(msg.Sender, "eradior@miuo1adm2.dns.miuoss") > 0 Then
     For Each objAtt In msg.Attachments
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder_h3gtn & "\" & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
  End If

End Sub

Sub TestSaveEmail()
   Call SaveEmail(ActiveExplorer.Application)
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line is the error?

Answer (score 1):

J Garth correctly identifies the first error that would be encountered if you tried to run `TestSaveEmail` but does not offer a correction.  Were you trying to use Explorer?  If so, try this:

```
Sub TestSaveEmail()
  Dim Exp As Outlook.Explorer
  Dim ItemCrnt As MailItem

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No emails selected"
  Else
    For Each ItemCrnt In Exp.Selection
      Call SaveEmail(ItemCrnt)
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

If your code encounters another error, you need to read R3uK's comment and tell us which line gives the error.

**Updated from my comment**

You should check that at least one mail item is selected but, if you really only want to save one email, try the following:

```
Sub TestSaveEmail()
  Dim Exp As Outlook.Explorer

  If Exp.Selection.Count = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "No emails selected"
  Else
    Call SaveEmail(Exp.Selection(1))
    Next
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm using the Outlook client itself. What Explorer are you referring to? Bear in mind that this exact code was working fine 2 days ago...thing is, it shows me the "type mismatch" error without indicating the line...

Comment: @Mircea  I do not see how this code could have been working 2 days ago.  Your code includes `Call SaveEmail(ActiveExplorer.Application)` which gives the impression you are trying to use Explorer. However, `ActiveExplorer.Application` is an object of type `Application`; it is not a `MailItem`.  `Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)` is a `MailItem`.  It is the first or only selected mail item.  So `Call SaveEmail(Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1))` would get past the first hurdle.  My code shows how to process all the selected emails not just the first. Note `Application` is optional.

Comment: yap your right - didn't see the comment almost posted an answer similar to your comment

Comment: @0m3r  I have done the same: posted an answer and only later noticed that my answer is included in someone else's comment.  Perhaps it would be better not to give extra information in a comment.  Adding it to the answer makes much more visible.

Comment: The TestSaveEmail() subroutine shouldn't influence the rest of the code. But if I delete it, I cannot run the macro. Why is that?

Comment: @Mircea  `SaveEmail` has a parameter: `msg`.  A function with a parameter can be called from cell as a UDF.  A subroutine or function with a parameter can be called from another macro but cannot be called from the keyboard.  Without `TestSaveEmail` you have no method of calling `SaveEmail`.  You could put the code of `TestSaveEmail` inside `SaveEmail` and drop the parameter if this is the only way you call `SaveEmail`.  Have you tried my code?  Have you managed to run `SaveEmail`?  Are there any errors in `SaveEmail`?

Answer (score 0):

This could be the issue.  You are passing an application object to the SaveEmail sub when it is expecting a MailItem object.  Try passing a message to the SaveEmail procedure instead of ActiveExplorer.Application.

```
Sub SaveEmail(msg As Outlook.MailItem)

Call SaveEmail(ActiveExplorer.Application)
```